# Print only pair numbers

Tags: javascript, html

So I did an assignment that does next: Type in 10 numbers, make only even numbers go out.
(klaraisara.co.nf/index.html) (Domain where I made the assignment)

```js
var korisnik = [];
var brojevi = [];
var br = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    korisnik[i] = window.prompt("Unesi broj");
    brojevi[i] = parseInt(korisnik[i]);
}

for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    if (brojevi[j] % 2 == 0) {
        br++;
        document.write(brojevi[j] + ' ');
    }
}

document.write("Bilo je " + br + " parnih brojeva");
```

Now I have a problem, 0 isn't even how do I get rid 0 coming out as an even number?
Note Korisnik = User, Brojevi = Numbers, Bilo je = there was, parnih brojeva = even numbers

Comment: Zero **is** an even number. That's quite basic: zero is an integer multiple of 2 (0 = 0 x 2).

Comment: [Parity of zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_zero)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Zero is an even number. In other words, its parity—the quality of an
>   integer being even or odd—is even. The simplest way to prove that zero
>   is even is to check that it fits the definition of "even": it is an
>   integer multiple of 2, specifically 0 × 2. As a result, zero shares
>   all the properties that characterize even numbers: 0 is divisible by
>   2, 0 is neighbored on both sides by odd numbers, 0 is the sum of an
>   integer (0) with itself, and a set of 0 objects can be split into two
>   equal sets."  ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_zero))

If you do not want 0 to be included change `j` to `1` instead so the counter starts at 1 - 10:

```
for (j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
  if (brojevi[j] % 2 == 0) {
     br++;
     document.write(brojevi[j] + ' ');
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, even though my professor doesn't let us believe 0 is a pair number